# Unable to make or receive calls on iPhone 5s.

Tags: iphone

Can't place or receive calls on my iPhone5s. Call failed comes up. Tried the *#31# option - not working. Tried turning phone off and then back on after several hours - doesn't work. Tried a few other options too. Please help!

Comment: What happens if you try to call your phone from another phone?

Comment: Similar question just asked: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236826/my-iphone-6s-can-receive-calls-send-and-receive-texts-and-use-facetime-but-ca

Comment: Same thing. Nothing comes through and no call goes out.

Comment: Have you tried calling your network provider?

Comment: No, there are 5 of us on the same account. No one else has this problem.

Comment: Might be worth giving them a try anyway. Also, perhaps edit your post to outline what the 'other options' you tried were.

Comment: I have the same issue, when I contacted the provider they issued me a new sim saying that might be due to old sim. It was ok for a day. Now I have the same issue.